# What are the eigenvectors of the superoperator $[H,\cdot]$ with $H$ the Hamiltonian?

Tags: projection-operator, linear-algebra

Let $\{A_\alpha\}$ be a set of hermitian operators and $\{\Pi(\varepsilon)\}$ a set of projectors on the (finite-dimensional) $\varepsilon$ subspace. Define $$A_\alpha(\Delta\varepsilon)=\sum_{\varepsilon\varepsilon'\atop{\varepsilon-\varepsilon'=\Delta\varepsilon}}\Pi(\varepsilon)A_\alpha\Pi(\varepsilon') $$
(notice how the sum is on every $\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon'$ such that the difference of the two is $\Delta\varepsilon$). Given $H=\sum_\varepsilon\varepsilon\Pi(\varepsilon)$, I should prove that the $A_\alpha(\Delta\varepsilon)$ are eigenvectors of the superoperator $[H,\cdot]$.

My own calculations don't quite give the correct result... could anyone give a quick proof?

Comment: What is $\Delta\varepsilon$? How do you define subtraction of subspaces? Are subspaces assumed to be $(n-1)$-dimensional and hence identified by a vector?

Comment: @AdamZalcman Edited for clarity. I'm working with finite-dimensional spaces; as I stated $\Delta\varepsilon:=\varepsilon-\varepsilon'$ is the gap between the two eigenvalues $\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon'$.

Comment: out of curiosity, where did this encounter this problem/statement?

Comment: @glS It is useful to show that the Lamb Shift hamiltonian commutes with the original local hamiltonian in the derivation of Lindblad's equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume the subspaces are orthogonal, *i.e.* $\Pi(\epsilon)\Pi(\eta)=\delta_{\epsilon\eta} \Pi(\epsilon)$.

You are asking what is $[H,A(\Delta\epsilon)]$, with
$$H\equiv \sum_\epsilon \epsilon \Pi(\epsilon),
\qquad A(\Delta\epsilon)\equiv \sum_\eta \Pi(\eta+\Delta\epsilon)A\Pi(\eta),$$
for some arbitrary Hermitian matrix $A$.

Observe that
$$[H,A(\Delta\epsilon)] =
\sum_{\epsilon\eta} \epsilon [
\Pi(\epsilon),
\Pi(\eta+\Delta\epsilon)A\Pi(\eta)
] \\
= \sum_\eta \left((\eta+\Delta\epsilon) - \eta \right)
\Pi(\eta+\Delta\epsilon)A\Pi(\eta)
= \Delta\epsilon \sum_\eta\Pi(\eta+\Delta\epsilon)A\Pi(\eta) \\
\equiv \Delta\epsilon A(\Delta\epsilon),
$$
which proves the statement: $A(\Delta\epsilon)$ is an eigenvector for $\operatorname{ad}(H)$ (that is, for the operator $X\mapsto [H,X]$), with eigenvalue $\Delta\epsilon$.

Note that the result isn't surprising: generally speaking, the eigenvalues of $\operatorname{ad}(H)$ are differences of eigenvalues of $H$, which is a result used *e.g.* when studying Lie algebras, see *e.g.* [this post on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/150272/173147).

Comment: Thank you, writing $\eta+\Delta\epsilon$ instead of keeping that condition on the sum makes it easy.

Comment: It looks like this proof doesn't need/use hermitianity of $A$ anywhere, does it? So the statement should be valid for any (bounded?) linear operator on the Hilbert space?